# Products not showing up in category after enabling Solr on Magento 1.14 EE

Tags: php, magento, solr, full-text-search

When using Mysqlfulltext products show up in categories accordingly, however when I change the Search Engine to Solr categories show as not having any products. I have re-indexed both via admin and the shell and also tried clearing the cache. The logs don't show any errors.

I am using Solr 3.6.2. Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Are present products in the solr?

Comment: Did you query Solr with prod id for data existence.

Comment: Might be Solr connection settings in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jetty or tomcat? If you are using jetty you need to make sure that Jetty is running by using the command below.

```
sudo service jetty check
```

Then you need to start solr and reindex the Magento from shell script.

You can refer the below tutorial to install jetty and start solr.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-on-ubuntu-14-04